# libpng 1.616 crashing on png_read_png in VS2012 C++

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, access-violation, libpng, first-chance-exception

I am on win7 64bit home edition. All of my projects are set to build in a 32bit environment using C++. I have successfully built libpng in debug mode using MDd runtime.  I have two active projects. My first project is in VS2010 and my second is in VS2012. Within my computer I created an environment variable set to the path for this library to make linking easier in my projects. Both my projects are using MDd as well as multibyte which is the same that libpng uses. All of my paths and dependencies are correct. I also copied over the libpng16.dll into both projects within the same directory as their built executable. I can successfully compile and build both projects. My VS2010 project runs and renders the loaded PNG graphic, however my project in VS2012 doesn't. It crashes when I call png_read_png throwing and unhandled exception that breaks on this line:

```
check = fread( data, 1, length, png_voidcast( png_FILE_p, png_ptr->io_ptr ) );
```

within pngrio.c. giving this error:

```
First-chance exception at 0x77308E19 (ntdll.dll) in Game_debug.exe: 0xC0000005: 
Access violation writing location 0x00000014.
```

The problem is not within my source code since I know that it works in my VS2010 project and I am using the same implementation to load the png in my VS2012 project. I am not sure off hand if it makes a difference that the library I am linking to was built in VS2010 or if there are some command line / compiler settings within the VS2010 built library that my VS2012 project doesn't like. I've read through the png documentation and searched online for hours and couldn't seem to find anything relevant. Any kind of help, tips, pointers or suggestions would do me a great deal.

Comment: I bet that your `png_ptr` is `NULL`. Can you use a debugger or something?

Comment: It isn't my project that is causing the crash, it is the PNG lib that is doing so. This library works fine when I link it to my VS2010 project but crashes when I link it to my VS2012 project. I'm using the same path/s & libs to link and build using the same runtime library build conventions and using the same methods in reading and creating a png texture for rendering. There are other functions being used from the libpng before png_read_png() is being called, and they open and verify that this file is a valid PNG file.

Comment: I'm not looking for blame. I'm just saying that this pointer is likely `NULL`.

Comment: I understand, I am grateful for the response.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After considerable hours of trial and errors, and with the little bit of help from others I was finally able to successfully build my 2012 project using the same version of libpng. What I had to do was in my directories where the libpng is located I had to create 3 Folders

1. VS2010\lpng1616\  , VS2010\zlib-1.2.8
2. VS2012\lpng1616\  , VS2012\zlib-1.2.8
3. VS2013\lpng1616\  , VS2013\zlib-1.2.8

And within each of these 3 folders I had to open libpng' solution within the respected versions of Visual Studio. Build out both release and debugs.

Then on my computer for the environment variables, I had to create not one but 3.

1. PNG_SDK_2010  set to  VS2010\lpng1616\
2. PNG_SDK_2012    "     VS2012\lpng1616\
3. PNG_SDK_2013    "     VS2013\lpng1616\

Then go back into my VS2010 and VS2012 projects set the paths using the environment variables accordingly replace the old stale libraries with the newly built ones, did a clean of the solution and both projects work properly!

So in conclusion if you are using outside libraries that you can download from the net that comes with a solution that you need to open and build out yourself to link against and you need this same library for projects across different versions of Visual Studio then you will have to open the solution that came with that library within the same version of Visual Studio that you are planning on using with your current project. I hope that my own situation comes to serve as an answer for others!

Answer (score 5):

Read the file projects/vstudio/readme.txt in the libpng source code, in particular the paragraph starting at line 41.

You are passing a (FILE*) to libpng, probably using png_init_io.  Visual Studio crashes inside fread when it tries to access the underlying FILE structure.

This is because you created the FILE* using fopen from one Visual Studio runtime but libpng is linked against a different Visual Studio runtime (msvcrt or something like that); the two runtimes are incompatible.

There are quite a number of ways to cause this to happen but it will almost certainly happen if you use a zlib DLL.  Are you using projects/vstudio to build libpng or did you try to do it yourself?  If you didn't use projects/vstudio you are on your own ;-)

1) Don't build both libpng and zlib into separate DLLs; link a libpng DLL against a static zlib (this is what projects/vstudio does) or use a static libpng (not a DLL) in your project (projects/vstudio also builds one of these.)

2) Read up on the various Visual Studio runtimes.  Everything that you run must use exactly the same runtime; check every project to see what runtime it has.  Preferably use the default (/MD)

3) If you think you have encountered a bug in libpng link your application statically (i.e. don't use any DLLs built by Visual Studio) and try again.  Windows DLLs are fine; it's the Visual Studio ones that use the Visual Studio runtime that break everything.

4) If the problem happens when you link statically make sure your DEBUG settings are the same everywhere.  You can't mix'n'max DEBUG because the debug version of the MSVC runtimes (any of them, even pre-Visual Studio) are not compatible with the release versions.

In fact it is ***better not to use png_init_io***; libpng supports this.  Provide your own read and write callbacks.  You *can* use stdio in those (fread) safely because they are implemented in the same DLL (the one you write) as calls fopen.  So long as you don't pass a (FILE*) across a DLL boundary you should be safe, maybe; no one has ever explained or understood the two DLL (zlib, libpng) behavior.

John Bowler

Comment: I downloaded the newest libpng from their website in a zip file. I then extracted its contents to a designated folder of choosing. Afterwards, I downloaded the newest version of zlib as a zip file and extracted its contents to the same root folder as libpng. I then went into the libpng's directories and opened its solution. Before I tried to build the library in either debug or release mode, I opened the zlib props file that comes with libpng to make sure the proper path / version of zlib is in the props(xml) file. By default the path and version match...

Comment: The libpng project settings has dependencies set for zlib and the build order is automatically set. The only thing in the libpng that I do change if it is needed is the runtime library setting if needed. With what you said above I will take that into consideration and go back over it. I might try to take the libpng default solution and try to open it with VS2012 and build it there instead of VS2010.

Comment: Then you have a libpng DLL that is correctly linked and, I assume, used "release DLL".  This runs a set of checks to make sure the DLL actually works, I assume they all passed.

Comment: So you need to examine the project runtime settings for whatever calls 'fopen'; I know you call png_init_io because otherwise fread wouldn't be called.  I suspect you will find that the crashing project somehow got build against a runtime other than the default (/MD); probably /MT (release multithreaded.)  It is *very* difficult to get this right, changing the settings doesn't always seem to result in a rebuild.

Comment: Thank you for the feed back. It is very insightful and your response is close. After reading your answer and having a second look at the libpng and my projects; I knew the problem was not with the runtimes since the lib worked in my VS2010 project. You did help to lead me to fix the problem. I described it in my own answer. It has to do with which version of VS the library was built in and which version of VS the project is built in that you are linking against. If making a project in VS10 then build the lib in VS2010 if in VS2012 or VS2013 then build your libs in VS2012 or VS2013.

Answer (score 1):

Just faced the same issue with libpng and curl
Both lib and curl use "msvcrt.dll"
So I just added nasty workaround

```
HMODULE h = LoadLibraryA("msvcrt.dll");
typedef FILE * (*FP)(char *f, char *m);
FP myf = (FP)GetProcAddress(h, "fopen");
if (myf)
{
    fp = myf((char *)lpszFileName, "wb");
}
```

and it worked for me.
Smells bad, but no matter

Slso, the advantage is that it works well for both debug and release version